# AWS Chime JavaScript SDK: addDeviceChangeObserver doesn't appear to be firing

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I am using AWS' Chime JavaScript SDK, and am running into an issue with the `addDeviceChangeObserver` method that lives on the `AudioVideoFacade`. Simply put, it doesn't appear to be firing any of the observer methods when my devices change. (i.e. when I unplug my headset, no observer methods fire - but I confirm my devices are no longer listed in the system settings.)

This is roughly how it looks when I set the observer:

```
import ChimeDeviceChangeObserver from '../chime/ChimeDeviceChangeObserver';
...
audioVideo.addDeviceChangeObserver(ChimeDeviceChangeObserver);
```

This is my ChimeDeviceChangeObserver class:

```
export default class ChimeDeviceChangeObserver {

  audioOutputsChanged(freshAudioOutputDeviceList) {
    console.log('Output list changed', freshAudioOutputDeviceList);
  }

  audioInputsChanged(freshAudioInputDeviceList) { 
    console.log('Input list changed', freshAudioInputDeviceList);
  }

  videoInputsChanged(freshVideoInputDeviceList) {
    console.log('Video list changed', freshVideoInputDeviceList);
  }

}
```

When I unplug/replug my device(s) none of the observer methods log as expected. I've doubled checked that my observer method names match the [AWS SDK docs](https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-js/interfaces/devicechangeobserver.html), and am at a loss what for to check next.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, embarrassingly, the answer is super straightforward!

Simply, I did not initiate the ChimeDeviceChangeObserver instance before passing it into `audioVideo.addDeviceChangeObserver()`.

Before I had the line as:
`audioVideo.addDeviceChangeObserver(ChimeDeviceChangeObserver);`

The fix being: `audioVideo.addDeviceChangeObserver(new ChimeDeviceChangeObserver());`

Instantiating the new class object correctly passed the observer class to Chime's sdk and the observer methods correctly fire now.